# Run Elevated Application from User Login Script

Tags: windows

I am trying to stop Microsoft Edge from continually taking over the file association for PDF files.  I found the (a?) solution to this here http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-resetting-file-associations/.  File associations are user specific so I want to update the registry for each user in their login script.  While this will stop Edge from taking over PDFs in the future, it won't fix the current association.  For that, I was thinking I could use the ASSOC command (assoc .pdf=AcroExch.Document) to reset their association back to Acrobat.  Unfortunately, Microsoft has decided that the ASSOC command needs to run under elevated privs (WHY?!? - the user can set their associations without elevating).

Is there a way to run something elevated from a user login script?  If not, any other suggestions on how to reset the file association?